# How to display Telugu font in UITextveiw in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In a `UITextView` is it possible to set the fontname.I want to display Telugu font in `UITextview`.This is the Telugu font family name "TeluguSangamMN-Bold".I am declaring Telugu font family in `UITextview`.But it is not worked for me.help me any body.

This is my code..

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

if(connection==urlConnection)

{

NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"String Response is : %@",strResponse);

NSRange r;

NSString * cleanString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strResponse];

while ((r = [cleanString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)

cleanString = [cleanString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"\n"];

text1.text=cleanString;

}

}

-(void)viewDidLoad

{

text1=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, 300, 80)];

text1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"TeluguSangamMN-Bold" size:12];

text1.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

text1.editable=NO;

[self.view addSubview:text1];

}
```

Comment: Remove the line text1.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; its not required.

Comment: check this link ---> http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom fonts in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737788/custom-fonts-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1):

[image]Check wheter you have added the font file with extension .dfont ot .ttf in plist

Comment: please tell me i have no idea about that

Comment: check this link --> http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: You can add new items with new font files

Answer (score 1):

The font your trying to use is included in iOS 7.0.

You can check the installed font list [Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5878)
Also in the nib file under `Fonts` it is displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you add the custom font file to INFO.PLIST
2. Also the file name is not same as the font family name, try to loop into `[UIFont familyNames]` and check whether your font family name is listed.
3. try to use the same family name in `text1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"TeluguSangamMN-Bold" size:12];`

Answer (score 0):

First download your relevant font

Add your custom font into your project , i.e. Dragged the font file(Berlin Sans FB.TTF) into XCode project.

Add a new entry with the key "Fonts provided by application".

[image]

Now use this font in your textview

```
txtview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Berlin Sans FB" size:15];
```

i used Berlin Sans FB you use your teleugu font

for more detail check [this link](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)