# How to use custom fonts in Storyboard for iOS 7 and 8 simultaneously?

Tags: ios7, storyboard, ios8, custom-font

Until now, I've been working on a iOS7 project with Xcode 5, and included the fonts via runtime attributes ([Custom font in a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard))

The other day I had to download iOS8 > Xcode 6, and the current method to import fonts and use them in storyboard is just drag the font in the project and set it as a custom font ([How to do Custom Fonts at design time in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102468/how-to-do-custom-fonts-at-design-time-in-xcode-6))

The problem is, the second way is not currently working with a device with iOS7, and if I add the runtime attribute fontName, it works with iOS7 but stops working with iOS8.

Any solution for working with iOS7/iOS8 at the same time?

Comment: When you say "Stops working with iOS 8" for the runtime attributes method, can you be more specific?  Is this using Objective-C or Swift?  Have you added the -all_load linker flag?