# How do I use a custom font in a SpriteKit project? - Swift

Tags: fonts, swift, sprite-kit, ios8, xcode6

I am new to swift, and I'd like to add a custom font to my SpriteKit project, however, after looking around, I cannot find a solution.

Comment: [SpriteKit does not make any difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737788/custom-fonts-in-ios-7).

Comment: Okay- but I still don't understand how to add custom fonts with iOS 8 & Swift.

Comment: I imagine the process would be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/21737788/

Answer (score 13):

1. First of all you need to drag the font into the project.
2. After that you need to select the font and select the target Membership checkmark for your app as seen in the picture.

[image: Xcode window with selected target membership for the custom font]

3. After that you go to your Info.plist and add the filename of the font (with extension) in "Fonts Provided By Application"
4. Now you can finally use the font als you would use every other font. If it doesn't work as it should you can find out the name Xcode gave the font with

Swift:

```
for name in UIFont.familyNames() {
  println(name)
  if let nameString = name as? String{
    println(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(nameString))
  }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
for name in UIFont.familyNames {
    print(name)
    if let nameString = name as? String {
        print(UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: nameString))
    }
}
```

5. Now just use the font for example in your SKLabelNode.

Comment: That target tick is exactly what I was missing! Thank you for saving my head from hitting against a wall.

Comment: No problem, I wish you luck on your project! @AlexeySobolevsky

Comment: Your Swift 3 version still works in Swift 5. Needed to find out the name assigned, used what was in ["FontNamedHere"], Thank you.