# FontAwesome icon crash only when release mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, release, font-awesome

When my project in debug mode ,everything work fine.
But when I change to release mode, my app crash at

```
[_menuButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:30.0],
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                     } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the error message is

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

If I commented the code , it can run fine but all FontAwesome icon became question mark.

Any idea to fix it ? Please help , thanks a lot !

Comment: What is `kFontAwesomeFamilyName` defined as?

Comment: You probably didn't import the font correctly. Hence `fontWithName` retuning `nil`.

Comment: I use the lib in my project https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the error message warns you something becomes nil while inserting, so you need to check which object is nil.

There is a high possibility reason:

`[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:30.0]`

In release mode, `kFontAwesomeFamilyName` cannot be recognized, or the font file is not bundled into your app, so `fontWithName` returns nil.

Comment: It is a library , I drag the source file to my projects . Why it cannot be recognized only in release mode?

Comment: there could be lots of reasons, like compile rules are different in release and debug mode. can you try print out `[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:30.0]` in release mode?

Comment: check out http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737788/custom-fonts-in-ios-7

Comment: I find out my Info.plist and Info_debug.plist have different setting on Fonts provided by application . It works fine now ! Thank you so much !!