# How to display icon using font ? ios

Tags: ios, svg, icons, uifont

I got a file(please find attached file) which contain font, this font supposed to display icons according to code number.
but i didn't succeed to display any icon with this font. here is my code:

```
    iconTest = UILabel();
    iconTest.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    onTest.center = self.view.center;

    iconTest.font = UIFont(name: "icomoon", size:16.0);
    iconTest.text = "e906";
```

what's the correct way to display icons using font !

[download font svg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8vnOWKrLfgMTV3SjJvX2M4MzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set text property like:

```
iconTest.text = "\u{e906}";
```

Do not forget to  [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737788/custom-fonts-in-ios-7) your custom font in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. **Install fonts** by double clicking on them.
2. Drag and drop fonts in Xcode and make sure they are added to target. (check `copy items if needed`)
3. In **info.plist**, set key **Fonts provided by application** and add **font name** for item(under key)
4. Set font type custom in storyboard for your controls or programatically assign font to `UILabel`

Code:

```
   //In swift 3
   let font = UIFont(name: "iconmoon", size: 15)
    btnSignout.setTitle("\u{e913}", for: UIControlState.normal) // set font icon on UIButton
    btnSignout.titleLabel!.font =  font

   // In objectiveC
   _lbl.text =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\ue92e"]; // set font icon on UILabel
   _lbl.font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"iconmoon" size:16];
```

Note: `\u` prefix is mandatory, Example for unicode `e626`, the label text should be `\ue626` or `\u{e626}`

Answer (score 0):

I use icon font in some of my projects. I have create a project to use icon font easily. The README of this project is written in Chinese. But the demo project will show everything clearly. https://github.com/JohnWong/IconFont

Icon font is always used in UILabel by setting text. But I think creating a UIImage from font is more flexible. This is why I create this project.
Method of register font by setting project is in answer provided by martin. Here is a way to register font by code: https://github.com/JohnWong/IconFont/blob/master/IconFont/TBCityIconFont.m#L16

Answer (score 0):

[Icomoon.swift](https://github.com/optonaut/Icomoon.swift): Use your Icomoon fonts with Swift - auto-generates type safe enums for each icon.

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's not IcoMoon, this library is worth noting:
https://github.com/0x73/SDevIconFonts

It integrates FontAwesome, Ionicons, Octicons and Iconic as Icon Fonts.

Assign them with code as easy as:

```
label.font = UIFont.iconFontOfSize(.FontAwesome, fontSize: 50.0)
label.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Twitter)
```

As noted before, you have to register the font files in your app's `Info.plist`.

Anyway, regarding IcoMoon: I would use the above library as a starting point. Should be fairly easy (*) to add IcoMoon in a fork (or better as a pull request).

(*) technically spoken, adding a list of convenience shortcuts like `.Twitter` is quite an expensive task when I have a look at https://github.com/0x73/SDevIconFonts/blob/master/SDevIconFonts/Classes/FontAwesome.swift.