# [NSNull pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in swift3 while using custom fonts

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to customize the font of the UISegmented control and i am using the following code as shown below:

```
let selectedfont = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Bold", size:22)
let unselectedfont = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:22)

let normalTextAttributes: [String: Any] = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 0.60, green: 0.60, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0),
  NSFontAttributeName: unselectedfont as Any
]
let selectedTextAttributes: [String: Any] = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
  NSFontAttributeName: selectedfont as Any
]

self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, for: UIControlState())
self.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTextAttributes, for: .highlighted)
self.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTextAttributes, for: .selected)
```

But the application crashes showing this:
 **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull pointSize]: unrecognized selector**

What is the issue here? Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Have you checked to see that `selectedFont` and `unselectedfont` aren't `nil`?

Comment: Before you put `selectedFont` and `unselectedFont` in attributes array, did you check if they are not nil?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: @ChelseaShawra, check that font's Family Name is used instead of file name. You could see it in Font Book app if font was installed in the system.

Comment: yes it is not showing in the font book

Comment: @ChelseaShawra, sorry, I meant PostScript Name: http://take.ms/Axk82

Comment: Thanks using the same name but the error is still coming

Comment: Roboto is a custom font, did you add it properly?

Answer (score 23):

Your call to `UIFont(name:,size:)` is likely returning `nil`.
Did you add the custom font [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21738096/2305521)?

1. Register the font in your info.plist adding the "Fonts provided by application" entry. Put the font file name, not the font name. Like `font.ttf`
2. Go to your project on the project navigator, click on the project name and go to *"Build phases"* then look down in *"Copy Bundle Resources"* go to the bottom, there are a lot of files and search for the "+" sign. A popup window will open with your project files. Search for your font file and add it to the bundle.
3. Finally check the font name. When you use it in your code, you have to use the font name, not the file name. To know the font name, double click on the font file in Finder and a window will open showing the font. Check that window title, that's the name of the font that you have to use.